# Cold boot attack on a NAS unit

Tags: linux, memory, security, encryption, nas

I'm familiar with the concept of cold boot attacks on laptop and desktop computers, where the goal is to find hidden encryption keys in the memory. I also think it's done on certain mobile phones. I also know it's hard to do, and some products like VeraCrypt now encrypt keys in memory in order to mitigate this attack.

I'm wondering, would this kind of attack also work on a NAS unit where the user uses volume or folder/file encryption? As far as I know QNAP offers volume encryption on NAS units, and Synology offers File/Folder based encryption. I assume that in order to work the encryption key to these volumes or folders/files has to remain in memory while the volume/folder/file is open for access.

My questions:

1. Does that mean that the keys are kept in the NAS units memory, and thus also are retrievable by an attacker with physical access?
2. If so, would it be natural to assume that the keys remain in the memory even after the volume/file/folder is dismounted/locked, until the unit reboots or the memory is overwritten with new data?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm familiar with the concept of cold boot attacks on laptop and
> desktop  computers, where the goal is to find hidden encryption keys
> in the memory

Typically, the memory is [zeroed at bootup](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec08/tech/full_papers/halderman/halderman.pdf)(page 13) so you would need to remove the memory and inspect it quickly to get what you want.  Some attacks include [spraying a can of air](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec08/tech/full_papers/halderman/halderman.pdf)(page 7) upside-down to cool the memory quickly so the bits don't change during transport to the reading device.  However, the memory is (probably) soldered on in an embedded application like a NAS box, so you would need quick access to the memory pins without loosing the data.

*["Ordinary DRAMs typically lose their contents gradually over a period of seconds"](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec08/tech/full_papers/halderman/halderman.pdf)* (page 2) *but it ["will persist for minutes or even hours if the chips are kept at low temperatures."](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec08/tech/full_papers/halderman/halderman.pdf)* (page 5)

> Does that mean that the keys are kept in the NAS units memory,
> and thus also are retrievable by an attacker with physical access?

They would have to be, otherwise crypto can't work.  Technically the key itself doesn't *need* to be in memory, but the round keys derived from the key by the key schedule, depending on the crypto algorithm, would be.  You would need to know what the key schedule looks like and scan memory to find it.  It is probably a kernel data structure, so you could walk the kernel structures and get to it in most cases.

> If so, would it be natural to assume that the keys remain in
> the memory even after the volume/file/folder is dismounted/locked, until
> the unit reboots or the memory is overwritten with new data?

Not if the crypto developer knows what they are doing.  Best practices for security are to zero memory (and flush related CPU caches) that was used for crypto keys and key-derived information.

For LUKS, you could unmount the volume and still have keys resident because LUKS is at the block layer---but if it is something at the filesystem layer like eCryptFS or some FUSE implementation then they keys are problaby (or at least should be!) zeroed in memory.

Comment: This is wrong. First, you don't need to physically remove the memory (a cold reset into modified firmware or a live OS works too), and second, none of these systems use SRAM, and SRAM isn't particularly affected by cold anyway. Finally, the key schedule itself is not stored in memory. It is the _round keys_ which are kept in memory, and these are generated from the master key _by_ the key schedule.

Comment: @forest, Thanks for correcting the finer points.  The post has been updated and I was able to find the original Usenix post that I remembered reading from so many years ago at PSU.  Cheers!  -Eric